# In .NET, why DataTable.Rows is DataRowCollection and not List?

Tags: .net, list, collections, coding-style

I am wondering that in .NET, why `DataTable.Rows` is type of `DataRowCollection` and not `List<DataRow>`? Is it because the `List<DataRow>` is encapsulated in `DataRowCollection` class and even provides extended functionality compared to the `List`? Or any other reason? Please throw some ideas...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataRowCollection` started in .NET 1.0, which predates generics. `List<DataRow>` could not have existed until the .NET Framework 2.0. During the 1.x days, the only way to make a strongly typed collection was to make your own class, like `DataRowCollection`.

It wasn't changed or updated to use `List<DataRow>` because that would be a major breaking change, and most likely because DataRowCollection does some specialized behavior that `List<T>` does not do.